# Как рисовать на WinUI-3 контролы из С++ библиотеки на directX

Tags: directx, winui3

Всем привет

У нас есть С++ либа, которая использует для рендеринга DirectX 9. Стоит задача использовать ее в WinUI-3 приложении на C#.

Ранее, когда стояла задача использовать эту библиотеку с WPF приложением делал так:

1. из С++ получал back buffer:

   IDirect3DSurface9 *pSurf = NULL;

   m_pD3Ddevice->GetBackBuffer(0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &pSurf);
2. Затем на шарпе использовал D3DImage контрол и в него делал D3DImage.SetBackBuffer(), передавая указатель полученный из С++ и флаг D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9

Но в WinUI 3 такого контрола нет (вроде как) и пока не могу найти работающего способа рендерить что-то на контролы из WinUI с помощью директX напрямую

Да, я нашел много разных упоминаний типа
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840262/uwp-and-directx

но не нашел ни одного работающего примера.

Может кто-то помочь найти работающий пример, чтобы понять как это люди делают, или описать механизм как имея С++ код с директХ рисовать по WinUI контролу?

Comment: Мне представляется, что рендеринг DirectX 9 на UWP напрямую явно работать не будет, так как DirectX 9 уже много лет как deprecated, и не поддерживается при работе с DXGI. Создавайте обычную DXGI swap chain и контекст DirectX11, а там как-нибудь передавайте данные с рендера Directx9.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/porting-your-directx-9-game-to-windows-store

Answer (score 1):

Немного истории. До WinUI была, и есть библиотека Windows.UI.XAML, и в ней такая возможность была (и есть) при помощи контрола `SwapChainPanel`.

```
// FILE: DirectXPage.xaml

<SwapChainPanel x:Name="swapChainPanel">
    <TextBlock Text="Test New App #1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontSize="30" />
</SwapChainPanel>
```

Далее, уже в С++ коде, он связывался с объектом `IDXGISwapChain4`:

```
// Объявление
winrt::com_ptr<IDXGISwapChain4> m_swapChain;

// Связывание ...
com_ptr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapChain;
check_hresult(m_dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForComposition(m_commandQueue.get(), &swapChainDesc, nullptr, swapChain.put()));
m_swapChain = swapChain.as<IDXGISwapChain4>();
m_swapChainPanel.Dispatcher().RunAsync(
    winrt::Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::High, [=]() {
        com_ptr<ISwapChainPanelNative> panelNative{ m_swapChainPanel.as<ISwapChainPanelNative>() };
        panelNative->SetSwapChain(m_swapChain.get());
    });
```

И, в конце концов, происходит отрисовка:

```
// Презентация
m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
```

Дело, однако, в том, что для это нужен DirectX 12 (никак не ниже, точно не версии 9, хотя есть теоретическая возможность использовать 11on12, но я не проверял):

```
// Такой девайс нужен
winrt::com_ptr<ID3D12Device5> m_d3dDevice;
```

Заканчивая повествование, `Microsoft.WinUI` создаётся "по образу и подобию" `Windows.UI.XAML`, но чтобы не зависеть от версии Windows. На данный момент (WinUI 3, WinAppSDK 1.1) реализации контрола `SwapChainPanel` в ней нет.

Кстати, полезная программa "WinUI 3 Gallery". Официально от Microsoft, в поиске найти можно. Её ценность, что прям в ней можно искать все текущие реализованные контролы и примеры их использования со ссылками на документацию.

Если без WinUI 3, а на "чистом" Windows UWP XAML C++, то выглядит совместное использование всего этого так:
[image: Windows UWP XAML C++ пример]